# How to output log only at error level?(Android OS)

Tags: android

My requirement is only output log at error level.

Attention:
(1). Not filtered by the adb logcat command or Android Studio ,etc.
(2). The system just only outputs log at the error level

Comment: For your app, you mean?

Comment: For System Global Area.    Not only for one app.

Answer (score 0):

Using logcat tool:

open the terminal / command prompt and use following command

> adb logcat "*:E"

If you want to save to a file:

> adb logcat "*:E" > logfilename.txt

Other log level,

```
V: Verbose
D: Debug
I: Info
W: Warning
E: Error
F: Fatal
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But you can see the Attention under my requirement.
 I don't want filter the log by adb locat command.